# Remove and replace a character from a jQuery variable and set as new variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

How do I remove a specific character (in this case "-") and replace it with a space and then use that as a separate variable elsewhere?

For example in this code I would like to get a version of the "name" variable that has the hypens stripped/replaced :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery(".tab").click(function(){
       var name=jQuery(this).attr("data-category");
        jQuery('body').removeClass('test');
        jQuery('body').addClass(name);
        jQuery(".name-copy").text(namewithoutspace);
    });       

});
```

Comment: `var namewithoutspace=name.replace(/-/g, ' ');` by this way you can just use it inside the click event .. to use it elsewhere you'll need to set it as a global variable

Answer (score 0):

use regex to match `-` and replace it by `replace()`

```
var namewithoutspace=name.replace(/-/g, ' ');

jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery(".tab").click(function(){
       var name=jQuery(this).attr("data-category");
        jQuery('body').removeClass('test');
        jQuery('body').addClass(name);
        jQuery(".name-copy").text(namewithoutspace);
    });       

});
```